# Testing corona project on xcode 7

Tags: xcode, sdk, coronasdk

As you know guys, now , testing your app in your actual device is allowed in xcode 7 without a developer account. Whay about that compatibility with corona ? How can I test my corona project in an actual device using xcode 7 ? Is there any explanation ?